# Mixing "Color"-values in java for image scaling with different portions

Tags: java, image, colors, pixel, image-scaling

I have an Image in the form of `Color[][]` array. It's kind of big so I want to scale it down: into another, smaller `Color[][]` array.

The problem is, that in this case I need to find the average color value of up to nine (probably not more) of the original images pixels, by the portions of how much space they take up in a certain pixel in the downscaled version of the image.

One of my (probably overcomplicated ideas) is to make it an RGB value and take the averages of all values, which might turn out to be a problem with the exact portions and colors not working that way.

It'd be nice to not have a huge code but instead just a simple solution or the hint that there isn't a short solution so that I can find a workaround.

Comment: For the scaling itself there are already many options (nearest neighbor, linear, bilinear, bicubic, lanczos...). For whatever reason you are storing an image as an array of `Color` objects (which is a **HUGE** waste of memory) : Could it be feasible to convert this array into a real `BufferedImage`, then scale this image down, and convert the resulting image back to an array of `Color` objects? (I doubt that any manual solution would be simpler or faster....)

Comment: yea I found out the method i wanted to do wouldn't work; so I'll just go with BufferedImage right away, ty :)